# XSL fetch min/max of modified attributes into variables

Tags: xslt

I would like to find a "nicer" solution to get the minimum and maximum values of attributes and save them into accesible variables. I would love to get away from the for-each-loop too. How is that possible?

My XML:

```
<Rows>
  <Entry value1="16,423" value2="18,123" />
  <Entry value1="423" value2="11,588" />
  <Entry value1="1,168" value2="521" />
</Rows>
```

And my XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Rows/Entry/@value1|Rows/Entry/@value2">
  <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:variable name="min" select="format-number(translate(.,',',''),'#')" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
      <xsl:variable name="max" select="format-number(translate(.,',',''),'#')" />
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The desired output should be $min=423 and $max=18123 as numbers and accesible outside the for-each-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is XSLT 2.0 since 2007 (implemented by XSLT processors like Saxon 9, AltovaXML, XmlPrime) where you can simply do (assuming you have the declaration `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` element):

```
<xsl:variable name="min" select="min(Rows/Entry/(@value1, @value2)/xs:decimal(translate(., ',', ''))"/>
<xsl:variable name="max" select="max(Rows/Entry/(@value1, @value2)/xs:decimal(translate(., ',', ''))"/>
```

If you really want to store a formatted string in a variable you can of course do that as well with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="min" select="format-number(min(Rows/Entry/(@value1, @value2)/xs:decimal(translate(., ',', '')), '#')"/>
<xsl:variable name="max" select="format-number(max(Rows/Entry/(@value1, @value2)/xs:decimal(translate(., ',', '')), '#')"/>
```

As for XSLT 1.0, there I think the sorting with `for-each` is the right approach but you would need to pull the `xsl:variable` outside the `for-each` e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="min">
 <xsl:for-each select="Rows/Entry/@value1|Rows/Entry/@value2">
  <xsl:sort select="translate(., ',', '')" data-type="number"/>
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#')"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="max">
  <xsl:for-each select="Rows/Entry/@value1|Rows/Entry/@value2">
   <xsl:sort select="translate(., ',', '')" data-type="number"/>
   <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(.,'#')" />
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

As an alternative you could replace the `for-each` with `apply-templates` and then write a template matching `@value1 | @value2` but while I think most tasks to transform nodes are better done using push style in XSLT I think for finding a minimum or maximum value the `for-each` is fine.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I cannot process XSLT 2.0 so I stuck to your XSLT 1.0 solution. And I figured

    number(translate(.,',',''))

is perfectly fine.

Comment: Addition for the XSLT 1.0 version: Since the numbers are not in valid number format at the time of sorting, we need to set `data-type="text"`, otherwise the results won't be sorted.

Comment: @thoughtgap, I put `<xsl:sort select="translate(., ',', '')"` in there to make sure the `comma` is removed before trying to sort as a number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is absolutely correct but I tried this for min

```
(/Rows/Entry/@value1|/Rows/Entry/@value2)[not((/Rows/Entry/@value1|/Rows/Entry/@value2) &lt; .)]
```

and this for max

```
(/Rows/Entry/@value1|/Rows/Entry/@value2)[not((/Rows/Entry/@value1|/Rows/Entry/@value2) &gt; .)]
```

and it gave me values you mentioned. But for simplification I worked with xml with values without ",".

Comment: Your solution still requires the for-each-loop, right? Variables defined in such a loop cannot be accessed from outside. Also, I think my solution (which is working, without outside variable access) would be more performant, because I do only two comparisons, wouldn't it?

Comment: Actually not. It should work in this way: `<xsl:variable name="min" select="(/Rows/Entry/@value1|/Rows/Entry/@value2)[not((/Rows/Entry/@value1|/Rows/Entry/@value2) &lt; .)]" />`. But as you mentioned the performance there I cannot recognize which attitude is better.